# Amortized analysis of dynamic array insertion

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis

I learned the amortized analysis of Prof Demaine's 6.006 videos. The Erik's thesis was, If we reallocate memory by doubling capacity => $$1 +2+4 + 8 + 16 +..+n = \theta(2^{lgn}) = \theta(n)$$ From Amortized analysis, we can say that after an operation we get linear complexity so the overall complexity of inserting is constant time. Then I thought what would be the complexity if we reallocate size by taking square of the previous size? I calculated the following : $$2 + 4 + 16 + 256 + .. + n = \theta(\sum_{i=0}^\sqrt{n} i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6} ) = \theta(n\sqrt{n})$$ so doing n operation takes $n\sqrt{n}$ complexity, inserting an element to a dynamic array has $\theta({\sqrt{n}})$ complexity. Is my approach correct?

Comment: You have to be careful with notations. You are using the notation: $n$ for almost everything. If you are doing $2+4+16+ \dotsc + n$, how the total insert operations are $n$? How sum of $i^2$ from $i = 1$ to $i = \sqrt{n}$ is $(n)(n+1)(2n+1)/6$? Please revise your solution.

Comment: Moreover, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about?